# Conditional Probability without mutual exclusiviness

Tags: probability

2 players, Player A and Player B are playing a football match. The probability that Player A will score is **0.20** and Player B will score is **0.30** and the probability that both of them will score is **0.15**.

Part A). What is the probability atleast one of them will score?
Part B). What is the probability that Player 2 will score given Player 1?

The way I have solved Part A is that I have used **Union** where $$P(A\cup B)= P(A)+P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$ implies $$P(A\cup B)= 0.20+0.30-0.15 = 0.35.$$ 
Is the first part correct I am not sure?

As for part B, I am not sure if I should use $$P(B|A)=P(A \cap B)/ P(A)$$

Comment: Yes to both parts.

Comment: Just as an extra, if you want to understand the intuition behind why we subtract the $P(A \cap B)$ term, it is because we over-count. Check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#/media/File:Inclusion-exclusion-3sets.png for a nice explanation.

Comment: @BruceET So why is Tien down saying the that part a is incorrect? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No idea. Maybe a misunderstanding or mis-labeling. Beyond the 'set up', I don't see a connection between the two parts. (a) Asks for $P(A \cup B)$ and (b) asks for $P(B|A).$ // A more clever problem might have been to say $P(A \cup B) = 0.35,$ $P(A) = 0.2,$ $P(B) = 0.3.$ Then ask for $A \cap B$ and $P(B|A).$